# Need to make ASP.NET MVC website with MySql Database and membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to set up an asp.net mvc website in which all user information is to be stored in mysql database and user authentication needs to implemented. The MySql database on located on a web hosting.

Till now, I have only relied on the default asp.net mvc project provided in visual studio and do not know much on how to setup membership and login functionality for a website.

Can anyone please advice where to start looking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link with custom [membership](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx) providers for MySql.
You will have to register them in Web.Config. Linked article explains well though.
When in doubt you can always refer to the sample Microsoft implementation. Their source is available [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx)

I've done several sites with custom membership providers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something non-typical, like MySQL in .NET, I would suggest that you at least make it as much non-typical-part-agnostic as possible. In your example, that would be membership provider based on DB-agnostic data access, that is Entity Framework. Then you can even "switch" your underlying DB later without pain.

Look here :

http://efmembership.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/EFMembershipProvider.aspx